# get value of access token

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, oauth-2.0, blogger, webapp2

I started using google API recently . I am using simpleauth https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth for authentication to google app engine . Now I am using google blogger API for publishing my blog and fetching data .

This API requires access_token value to use the API https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#RetrievingPostsForABlog for Authorization . I cant find a way to get value of access token .

Is there a way to get the value of acces token or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your webapp with Google to get a client ID and client secret.  Then, you can configure your OAuth2 library with these details to allow you to send fully authenticated requests from your webapp to Blogger.

For the specific scenario you listed, retrieving a blog post, I think you can follow [step 1 of this page](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#basicsteps) and then follow [these steps](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#APIKey).  You should be able to copy+paste the key from there into the query params of the GET request.

To issue fully authenticated requests, for publishing new posts, for example, you'll have to get your OAuth2 library with the client ID and client secret and have it issue the requests for you.